# Catalog price rule not excluding specific categories

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, catalog-price-rules, ce-1.9.1.0

I have set up a catalog price rule for a specific customer group. I want to exclude some different categories with this rule.

See setting in screen:
[image]

For some reason this is not excluding products OR categories.

This is in Magento 1.9.1.0

I have tested exact same settings in 1.7.0.2 where this works perfectly.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings in my screenshot are correct for excluding multiple categories and SKU's from some catalog price rule.

After banging my head against the wall for several day i tried changing away from flat category structure, which seemed to solve my problem. Category indexes must be currupt or something, but i did not investigate further.

Anyone else have this problem, try and do what i did and see if it works. Did in my case.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer so that the question does not count as unanswered anymore